# Show Options only when match found

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to make a search box which shows suggestions as soon as user starts typing in the search bar. Using `select2` it shows suggestions by default even when user does not type anything in the search box. Since I have large no. of options I don't want them to display all by default. It should be displayed only when match with the user typing in the search box.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Using Select2</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Select2 CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container bg-danger">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label>Multiple Select2</label>
          <select id="multiple" class="js-states form-control" multiple>
            <option>Java</option>
            <option>Javascript</option>
            <option>PHP</option>
            <option>Visual Basic</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Select2 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#multiple").select2({
          placeholder: "Select a programming language",
          allowClear: true
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the option `minimumInputLength` of the select2 configuration:

```
$("#multiple").select2({
          placeholder: "Select a programming language",
          allowClear: true,
          minimumInputLength: 2
      });
```

Now options will only appear after the user has typed at least 2 characters.